# Assigning the topics you've selected ins't allowed. A Salesforce Admin must enable topics for objects for the article type/s

Tags: articles, topics

I tried to Add Navigational Topcs but I encountered these problem, this is already in lightning Knowledge article "Assigning the topics you've selected ins't allowed. A Salesforce Admin must enable topics for objects for the article type/s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that for the Objects related to knowledge (Lets say you have objects like FAQ) needs to have Topics Enabled .

To enable the topic navigate to Set up|Customize|Topic| Topics For Objects and enable as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you you are correct, already saw from other forums. thanks much still! :)